# Select duplicate records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

This query works on SQL Server But in MySQL it's not working. Can anybody help?

```
SELECT name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
   Institution_Code =  1  and 
   Month= 6 and Year= 2016 and 
  Id IN (
          SELECT Id FROM table_name 
          where Institution_Code =  1 and 
                Month= 6 and Year= 2016 
          GROUP BY Id HAVING count(Id) > 1 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the reserved word in your query:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE Institution_Code = 1 
and `Month`= 6 
and `Year`= 2016 
and Id IN (
    SELECT Id 
    FROM table_name 
    where Institution_Code = 1 
    and `Month`= 6 
    and `Year`= 2016 
    GROUP BY Id 
    HAVING count(Id) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE Institution_Code = 1 
and [Month]= 6 
and [Year]= 2016 
and Id IN (
    SELECT Id 
    FROM table_name 
    where Institution_Code = 1 
    and [Month]= 6 
    and [Year]= 2016 
    GROUP BY Id 
    HAVING count(Id) > 1 )
```

SQL reserved word must be enclose to this bracket [reserved word here]

Answer (score 0):

you may be try this

```
SELECT * , count( 'name' ) is_duplicate
FROM `tbl_name`
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING is_duplicate >1
```

Comment: not working it show whole data but i want only duplicate data

Comment: SELECT * , count( 'name' ) is_duplicate
FROM `tbl_name`
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING is_duplicate >1  try this